# Oracle-adf selectOneChoice reset on treeTable scrolling

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm facing problem with a selectOneChoice inside a TreeTable in clickToEdit mode.
When scrolling down and returning up, the value of the combo of the focused row is cleaned.
To replicate the issue, just navigate to the ADF demo :
[clickToEditTreeTable](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/table/clickToEditTreeTable.jspx)

1. Expand all
2. Select the first row
3. Change the value of the Col2 to HeadPhone
4. With the focus still on first row, scroll down until the Fetching Data message appear
5. Scroll up back to the first row
6. The value of the Col2 is changed to Mouse

How can i avoid this ?
In my application i have noticed that the value change listener is fired the first time when changing the value, and a second time while scrolling the treeTable,setting it to null

This problem occurs ONLY with a treeTable in editingMode clickToEdit.
The standard table works fine.

My jdev is 11.1.2.1.0.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it on the jdev 11.1.2.4? Could be a bug.

Comment: i have tried on the demo online, that is supposed to be developed with the latest jdev version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to reproduce this issue in ADF demo itself its either an ADF bug or limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats a kind of a bug. You can try to file service request on it.
It seems that since you don't commit your changes (because you still stays on this row). On another fetch your changes ain't being saved and on refetch you getting old values.
As for workaround for this issue:

1. If your tree ain't too large, you can set iterator **RangeSize** to **-1** to fetch all rows at once to avoid more rows fetching. However if you have a lot of rows, you'll have a perfomance issues.
2. You can try to set **autosubmit** property on this field to **true**, so it will save your data (and hopefully load) on comback (even if it don't, you can do it in your bean). May be you will also need to put there **clientListener** to submit data, when your control loses focus.
3. Don't use clickToEdit for this control or call it a feature (no submit - no changes) :)

Comment: Thx Nagh i'll try to open a ticket.

Comment: For your workarounds:  1. My tree is 60 columns, with 30 editable fields, and can have a size > 500 , so i need a fetch size < 100.  2. The autosubmit is already set to true.  3. The tree is too big i really need it :).

Comment: Pay attention that autosubmit alone may be not enough, you need to handle onblur event to force submit event, when user leaves the field.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't wait a fix, i have found a workaround to the problem.
The value is setted to null ( or false for the checkboxes ), when the element is renderized the second time on scrolling back, because the setter property of the bean and ( if present )  the value change of the selectOneChoice are invoked.
So i have setted a clientListener on the valueChange event that unlike the valueChangeListener is fired correctly, and a fake property as value.